# Annotation SpringBootTest ignores my tests

Tags: java, spring-boot

Let say I have a Spring Boot Project, based on SpringBoot, including the following dependencies in `pom.xml`:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

SpringBoot has the version `2.7.18`, surefire has the Version `2.22.2` and Junit `5.8.2`. My maven version is `3.9.6`

Now, I have some testclasses, following the convention, that the filename ends with `Tests.java`.
For some tests, I need specific properties, which are usually set by the file `application.properties`. Instead of using more files, I would like to use the `@SpringBootTest-Annotation`, like this:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
//Other imports

@SpringBootTest(properties={"testproperty=value"})
public class ExampleTests {
    @Test
    public void ExampleValidTest() {
        // Do some testing
    }
}
```

If I run now `mvn clean package`, this will find all other tests given in other testclasses, but NOT this test marked by the annotation. If I delete this annotation, this test will be executed, but failed (which is obvious based on a wrong property value).

Is there anybody, who can help here?

Comment: No, sry , this was just missing quotes in the example here. I have corrected it.

Comment: I have to use Java 8, therefore in my opinion, I have to stay at SpringBoot 2.7.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing dependency `spring-boot-test` by `spring-boot-starter-test`:

this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

by

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This should solved your issue